# Pagination does not work fine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I want to add pagination to my page using ajax. I have referred this link http://www.infotuts.com/ajax-pagination-mysql-php-and-jquery/ and tried to follow the code.

But result I got is different than the demo. http://www.infotuts.com/demo/ajax-pagination-php-mysql-jQuery/

when the page is first loaded it shows first page but numbers are starting from 17 and when I move from page to page in between shows blank records for some page.

Not working like demo: http://www.infotuts.com/demo/ajax-pagination-php-mysql-jQuery/

Also dose not show which page is selected.

Here is link to my page :

http://104.131.162.126/agtvapp/index.php

dbmanipulate.php

```
  <?php
include('Database.php');

$limit = 3;
$adjacent = 3;

 if(isset($_REQUEST['actionfunction']) && $_REQUEST['actionfunction']!=''){
$actionfunction = $_REQUEST['actionfunction'];

   call_user_func($actionfunction,$_REQUEST,$limit,$adjacent);
}
function showData($data,$limit,$adjacent){
  $page = $data['page'];
   if($page==1){
   $start = 0;  
  }
  else{
  $start = ($page-1)*$limit;
  }

    $database = new Database(Constants::DBHOST,Constants::DBUSER,Constants::DBPASS,Constants::DBNAME);

    $dbConnection = $database->getDB();
    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("select * from posts order by pt_id asc");
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();


    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("select * from posts order by pt_id asc limit $start,$limit");
    $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt->execute();
    $data = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $str ='<table><tr><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Likes</th><th>Views</th><th>Url</th></tr>';

    if(count($data)>0){

   foreach($data as $row){
       $str .= '<tr><td>' . $row['title'] . '</td> <td>' . $row['description'] . '</td><td>'.$row['likes'].'</td><td>'.$row['views'].'</td>';

       if (strcmp($row['url_type'],"2") == 0 || strcmp($row['url_type'],"3")  == 0)
       {
           $str .= '<td><a href="'.$row['url'].'" target="_blank"><image  alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'na.jpg\';"  src="'.$row['thumb_url'].'" height="150" width="150"></image></a></td></tr>';

           /*  $posts.= '<td>'.$row['url'].'</td></tr>';*/

       }

       elseif(strcmp($row['url_type'],"6")  == 0){

           // $parts = parse_url($row['url']);
           //  $urls=$parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'] . $parts['path'];
           $thumb_url = $row['url'];
           $url = $thumb_url . "media";
           /*               $posts.= '<td>'.$thumb_url.'</td></tr>';*/


           $str .= '<td><a href="'.$row['url'].'" target="_blank"><image alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'na.jpg\';"  src="'.$row['thumb_url'].'" height="150" width="150"></image></a></td></tr>';

       }
       elseif(strcmp($row['url_type'],"7") == 0)
       {
           $str = substr($row['url'], 0, strrpos($row['url'], '?'));

           $thumb_url = $str.'media';

           /*          $posts.= '<td>'.$thumb_url.'</td></tr>';*/

           $str .= '<td><a href="'.$row['url'].'" target="_blank"><image alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'na.jpg\';"  src="'.$thumb_url.'" height="150" width="150"></image></a></td></tr>';
       }
       elseif(strpos($row['url'],"https://scontent.fbom") !==false )
       {
           $str .= '<td><a href="'.$row['url'].'" target="_blank"><image alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'na.jpg\';"  src="'.$row['url'].'" height="150" width="150"></image></a></td></tr>';
       }
       elseif(strpos($row['url'],"https://www.facebook.com/") !==false){

           $facebookVideoId=getFacebookVideoID($row['url']);

           //create thumbnail link and videos link
           $json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$facebookVideoId.'');
           $obj = json_decode($json);

           //add thumbnail and video link in array
           $thumb_url = $obj->picture;
           $url =$obj->source;

           $str .= '<td><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank"><image alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'na.jpg\';" src="'.$thumb_url.'" height="150" width="150"></image></a></td></tr>';

       }
       elseif(strcmp($row['url_type'],"1") == 0)
       {

           $myvideo = $row['url'];
           $url = "videos/".$myvideo;

           $str .= '<td><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank"><image alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'na.jpg\';"  src="'.$url.'" height="150" width="150"></image></a></td></tr>';
       }

       elseif(strcmp($row['url_type'],"0") == 0)
       {
           $myImage = $row['url'];
           $url = "images/".$myImage;

           /*          $posts.= '<td>'.$url.'</td></tr>';*/

           $str .= '<td><a href="'.$url.'" target="_blank"><image alt="Image not found" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\'na.jpg\';"  src="'.$url.'" height="150" width="150"></image></a></td></tr>';
       }
       else{
           $str .= '<td><a href="'.$row['url'].'" target="_blank">'.$row['url'].'</a></td></tr>';
       }
   }

    } else {

        $str.='<td>No data found</td>';

    }

    function getFacebookVideoID($url) {
        preg_match("~/videos/(?:t\.\d+/)?(\d+)~i", $url, $matches);
        return $matches[1];
    }

    $str.='</table>';

echo $str;


pagination($limit,$adjacent,$count,$page);


}
function pagination($limit,$adjacents,$count,$page){
    $pagination='';
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $prev_='';
    $first='';
    $page = $count/$limit;
    $lastpage = ceil($page);
    $next_='';
    $last='';
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $prev_.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=$prev\">previous</a>";
        else{
            //$pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">previous</span>"; 
            }

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 5 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
        $first='';
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
            }
            $last='';
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 3 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            $first='';
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
                }
            $last.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=$lastpage\">Last</a>";            
            }

            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
               $first.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=1\">First</a>";   
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
                }
                $last.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=$lastpage\">Last</a>";            
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $first.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=1\">First</a>";  
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
                }
                $last='';
            }

            }
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $next_.= "<a class='page-numbers' href=\"?page=$next\">next</a>";
        else{
            //$pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
            }
        $pagination = "<div class=\"pagination\">".$first.$prev_.$pagination.$next_.$last;
        //next button

        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }

    echo $pagination;  
}
?>
```

script

```
 $(function(){
 $.ajax({
         url:"dbmanupulate.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"actionfunction=showData&page=1",
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){

          $('#pagination').html(response);

        }

       });
    $('#pagination').on('click','.page-numbers',function(){
       $page = $(this).attr('href');
       $pageind = $page.indexOf('page=');
       $page = $page.substring(($pageind+5));

       $.ajax({
         url:"dbmanupulate.php",
                  type:"POST",
                  data:"actionfunction=showData&page="+$page,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){

          $('#pagination').html(response);

        }

       });
    return false;
    });

});
```

style

```
  #mhead{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: georgia;
}
#pagination table{
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto;
    font-family:Tahoma,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
    padding:4px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.head{
    background:lightseagreen;
}
#pagination table tr td{
    padding: 8px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    border:1px solid #d1d1d1;
}



.pagination{
    width:600px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.pagination .current{
    padding: 4px 10px;
    color: black;
    margin: 1px 0px 9px 6px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    float: left;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background: whitesmoke;
}
.pagination .page-numbers{
    padding: 4px 10px;
    color: white !important;
    margin: 1px 0px 9px 6px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    float: left;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    background: #00b4cc;
}
```

I am not getting the issue,please help, thank you..

Comment: Can you get the values of $page, $count, $limit and $lastpage? ... inside pagination function. Just print it.

Comment: yes printed please check the link.@Hmmm

Comment: Shouldn't the page value be 1 ? I think there is issue of $page you want to load and this `$page = $count/$limit;` ... Just have different name may be ... $current_page or something. Makes sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the same variable `$page` inside your `pagination()`.So original `$page` is overwrite by new value.

Change your code:

```
$mpage = $count/$limit; //in your code it is => *$page = $count/$limit;* 
$lastpage = ceil($mpage); //in your code it is => *$lastpage = ceil($page)*
```

Comment: okk worked now. but it shows no records on page 3,4,5,6,22 , also I want limit as 15  per page if I changed $limit and $adjacent as 15 shows no records

Comment: What is your total `count`? Update your code in this link also `http://104.131.162.126/agtvapp/index.php`

Comment: I have updated the code it dose not show anything now as I changed $limit total count was 73

Comment: print_r($data) before foreach loop.

Comment: I am not getting $data on those pages.

Comment: Change your function definition: `showData($data,$limit,$adjacent)` to `showData($mydata,$limit,$adjacent)`Also change `$page = $data['page'];` to `$page = $mydata['page'];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141943/discussion-between-sid-and-dipanwita-kundu).